# Prove that the limit of a complex function holds

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}=0$

$|\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}|=\frac{|\overline{z}||\overline{z}|}{|z|}=|z|$ Right?, so we can let $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: Right! (.....  added characters to get to at least however many are needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, no need to go to epsilons and deltas in this case.   You have the norms go to 0, so the term goes to 0.